# auto-blending layers with Photoshop's scripting

Tags: scripting, photoshop, layer, blending

Does anyone know how to perform auto-blending layers (with selecting all possible ones, panorama mode, seamless tones and colors) by scripting in Photoshop?

Explaining what I exacly want to aim: I try to "rearrange some stitching" to a script. I think it's like creating a panormama image. When I have only few images, I can stitch them together taking this steps:
loading into stack,
autoblending layers (very important because my input images has some overlapping areas which aren't completely sharp),
merging layers,
some additional steps taking to improve quality of output image.

Now I can't do it manually because I've got almost 300 images of one scene for an object and ca.5 scences. I want to stitch each of 300 images with another 300 for another scene and so on until every scene is done. It leads to situation I have to perform stitching 1500 times...

I would be very grateful for any tips! I'm new here so I'm open to rewrite my question in a proper way if there is anything unclear.
Thanks!

P.S.
And til now I'm already familiar with looping over all images in a specific folder to choose two proper ones. Then I know how to load them into stack by scripting. I know also how to save new image and close images I don't need anymore. Only thing I cannot do is auto-blend layers...

Comment: Is this a coding question? If this is the case, please expand on what you've tried/want to do.  If not, maybe try asking your question at graphic design stack exchange.

Comment: Yes I meant it as a coding question. I've tried to specify my qyestion by edditing it. Thanks!

Comment: There are several questions on Photomerge script on SO,  does [any of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Photoshop+photomerge) answers your question? If no, why?

Comment: Thank you so much! I will be looking there!